# Simple code breaks when calling it from a function

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
secret_word = "secretword"
guess = ""

def askForGuess():
    guess = input("Introduce the secret word :")
    print(guess,secret_word)
    

while guess != secret_word:
    askForGuess()
    

 
print("You've won!")
```

If I call askForGuess() inside the while statement it will never print 'You've won!' not even if I introduce the secret word correctly.
However, if I just simply paste askForGuess() code inside of the while statement it works. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You have two _different_ variables named `guess`.  One is global, and one is a local variable inside the function.  Changing the local one has no effect on the global one.  If you want to use the global variable inside the function, put `global guess` at the top of the function so it knows to use the global one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As abe said, it is because there are two variables called `guess` in the two scopes.

Since the use of globals is not considered good code, my implementation of this would be:

```
secret_word = "secretword"
guess = ""

def askForGuess():
    guess = input("Introduce the secret word :")
    print(guess,secret_word)
    return guess

while guess != secret_word:
    guess = askForGuess()
    

 
print("You've won!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning some value to `guess` in the scope of your function `askForGuess()` doesn't change the value of the global variable `guess`, that's why you never get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What basically happens here is that the `guess` inside the loop is a *new variable* and not the one that the while loop checks. This is due to the fact that the ***guess*** variable in line 2 **has not be declared as global**. The following code should work

```
secret_word = "secretword"
global guess
guess = ""


def askForGuess():
    global guess
    guess = input("Introduce the secret word :")
    print(guess, secret_word)


while guess != secret_word:
    askForGuess()

print("You've won!")
```

Hope the above helps, well done for the well explained question.